# align-items: center not working in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, display, text-align

I am trying to vertically align the tex of a `nav` bar that is in `display: flex;`.
I have used the following code yet the text is still aligned to the top of the `nav` container and won't move down to the center.
Could you please help me understand what I have done wrong? I have tried moving `align-items: center;` to the `nav{}` and `nav ul li{}` in CSS but it doesn't change anything.

```css
nav {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Event Schedule</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Or nav ul {height: inherit}

Comment: remove the height and add overflow:auto instead

Answer (score 6):

Just add `height: 100%` to `nav ul`

```css
nav {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Event Schedule</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it but nothing changed. Text still aligned at the top. The only solution I have found to work so far is setting the line height in `nav ul` to the same as the nav bar using `px`. I.e `line-height: 70px;`.
This it what I was expecting your suggestion of `height:100%` to do so i'm surprised it didn't.....perhaps something else needs to be changed for that to work?

Answer (score 2):

The items are vertically aligned, or at least they try to be, but you have set the font size so large that they break out of your fixed-height container. Possible solutions:

1. Don't set the font-size.
2. Don't fix the height of the parent element.

Comment: Thank you for responding. As it's the nav bar I need the font size to be large for it to stand out. The only work around I have found so far is to set the `line-height` the same as the container `nav` which is the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of basic but worth mentioning- my issue was that I had a default margin I had to override. So if you're using a component that's used elsewhere/are overriding styles be sure you're checking margins/padding because that might be it!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).